# How to display an alert message if there is no data flutter

Tags: flutter

I am doing a query about the data from a mysql database and they are displayed in a list.

My problem is if there is no data in the database. I would like to display an alert message stating that or display a text to warn that there is no available data.

This is the code page that I use to display the data:

```
void main() {
  runApp(Your()

  );

}

class Your extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<Your> {
  MyPreferences _myPreferences = MyPreferences();
  String apiURL;
  var id;

  List<Flowerdata> _flowersDataForTheListView = List<Flowerdata>();

  Future<List<Flowerdata>> fetchNotes() async {
    id=_myPreferences.id;
   final String url  = 'https://=============/All.php?id=' + id.toString();
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var flowers = List<Flowerdata>();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      var flowersJsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      for (var flower in flowersJsonData) {
        flowers.add(Flowerdata.fromJson(flower));
      }

    }
    else{

    }
    return flowers;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchNotes();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return  _listItem(index);
      },


    );
  }


  _listItem(index) {
         return Column(

        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

           Row(
              children: [

                Flexible(

                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text( _flowersDataForTheListView[index].Name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17)),
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0,),

                    ],
                  ),

                ),

              ],
            ),


        ],




    );
  }
}
```

PHP contact page:

```
<?php




include 'connt.php';


  $id=$_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=? ORDER BY id DESC";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 

$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

 
//$result = $con->query($sql);
 
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 
 
     while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     
     $item = $row;
     
     $json = json_encode($item, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
     
     }
 
} else {
    echo "No";
}
 echo $json;
$con->close();

?>
```

How can I do this if someone knows please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be using MaterialApp in your flutter code, but if you use it, Scaffold widget has a method called `showSnackbar` where you can display a message that pops up at the bottom of the page.

Here is a sample code for `showSnackbar`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MyList(),
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchNotes();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> fetchNotes() async {
    // Here, you actually fetch the data from API
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    final flowers = [];
    if (flowers.isEmpty) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Data is empty'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```